# Get real info from Facebook user info

Tags: php, parsing, facebook-graph-api, get, userinfo

I've read the official documentation and a lot of docs on Google.
I would like to print the user info, but when I run my code, I got this:

```
Array
(
[id] => xxxx
[name] => Vinicius 
[first_name] => Vinicius
[last_name] => M
[link] => http://www.facebook.com/xxx
[username] => vinicius
[birthday] => 01/04/1989
...
```

And my code is, to get the user info:

```
//if user is logged in and session is valid.
if ($user){
//get user basic description
$userInfo = $facebook->api("/$user");
```

And to show:

```
<?php d($userInfo);  ?>
```

I would like to print like this (or something like):

```
Name: Vinicius
Last name: M
Birthday: 01/04/1989
```

I followed the Thinkdiff tutorial. Lots of code from them.

How about nested arrays?

```
[location] => Array (
    [id] => 110703698957912
    [name] => Campinas, Sao Paulo 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```php
echo 'First name: ' . $userInfo['first_name'];
echo 'Last name: ' . $userInfo['last_name'];
echo 'Birthday: ' . $userInfo['birthday'];
```

For nested arrays like:

```
[location] => Array (
    [id] => 110703698957912
    [name] => Campinas, Sao Paulo 
)
```

You can access them by doing:

```php
$userInfo['location']['id'];
$userInfo['location']['name'];
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you so much! God bless you! (you just forgot the semi-colon, haha!)

Comment: Hi again. 

How about the arrays that have more than one option?
Like:

    [location] => Array
    (
    [id] => 110703698957912
    [name] => Campinas, Sao Paulo
    )

Thanks!!!

Comment: $userInfo['location']['id']; $userInfo['location']['name'];